# How to teleport Armor Stands to coordinates

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a minigame in Minecraft and for that I need a command to teleport armor stands to a specific coordinate. Could anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to do this yourself? Arqade works best when we know what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Use the teleport command:

```
/tp @e[type=ArmorStand] X Y Z
```

Replace X, Y, and Z with the coordinates you want to teleport it to.